# JSON.NET parsing Twitter Archive issue

Tags: c#, json, twitter

I'm trying to parse the JSON that contains all your tweets with JSON.NET
Basically all I need is the value of "text" and "id".
This is currently the code I have for parsing it:

```
string file = ReadJSON(filename);
var parsedFile = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(file, typeof(ATweet));
```

The string file, is basically all the lines from any given .js file containing the twitter archive for that month. Excluding the first line, since the first line always makes the JSON parse fail.
And these are the classes I (try to) read these values into:

```
[JsonObject]
class ATweet
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "source")]
    public string Source { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "entities")]
    public ATweetEntities Entities { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "geo")]
    public string Location { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id_str")]
    public string IdStr { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "created_at")]
    public string CreationTime { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user")]
    public ATwitterUser Author { get; set; }

}

[JsonObject]
class ATweetEntities
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "user_mentions")]
    public string[] Mentions { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "media")]
    public string[] Media { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "hashtags")]
    public string[] HashTags { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "urls")]
    public string[] Urls { get; set; }
}

class ATwitterUser
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "screen_name")]
    public string ScreenName { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "protected")]
    public bool IsProtected { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id_str")]
    public string IdStr { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "profile_image_url_https")]
    public string ProfileImageUrl { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "verified")]
    public bool IsVerified { get; set; }
}
```

But when I try to run it, I get this exception at the JsonConvert.DeserializeObject line:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'ThisNamespace.ATweet' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
```

Answer (score 0):

Each element in your file needs to be a name value pair like this.

```
screen_name : value
profile_image_url_https : value
```